# Dropdown menu cover the button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

there is my code

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav">
                <li class="nav-item" (click)="onSelect('recipe')"><a href="#">Recipies</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" (click)="onSelect('shoping-list')"><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div 
                class="btn-group"
                appDropdown
                #r="appDropdown">
                <button 
                    class="btn btn-close-white dropdown-toggle"
                    type="button"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Menage<span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'show':r.isOpen}">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Dropdown directive
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appDropdown]',
    exportAs: "appDropdown"
})
export class DropdownDirective {

    @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;

    @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }
}
```

Problem is about dropdown menu, when you click on, it cover the button and it doesn't look good. Here you have screens of how it looks.[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJBVB.png)[And after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIPMj.png)

Comment: can you share the css of your dropdown-menu. This is more of a css issue then an Angular one so I would recommend changing your tags of the question to have more success in finding answers.

Comment: I dont use css here I am using bootstrap but just common bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `btn-group` class on the surrounding `div` with `dropdown`

```html
<div class="dropdown" appDropdown #r="appDropdown">
...
</div>
```

see working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-enedky?file=src/app/app.component.html) only the colors are acting weird but you can click the whitespace.